# PHP - Iterate over google results

Tags: php, file, curl, iteration

I have a simple CURL script that searches Google for "Batman", then saves the result in a file...

Can someone tell me a good way of iterating through the file to find each of the search results title and URL, please?

This is my code:

```
function get_remote_file_to_cache()
{
    $the_site = "https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enSE555SE556&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=batman";


    $curl = curl_init ();
    $fp = fopen ( "temp_file.txt", "w" );
    curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $the_site );
    curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp );

    curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );

    curl_exec ( $curl );

    $httpCode = curl_getinfo ( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
    if ($httpCode == 404)
    {
        touch ( 'cache/404_err.txt' );
    } /*
    * else { touch('cache/'.rand(0, 99999).'--all_good.txt'); }
    */
    else
    {
        $contents = curl_exec ( $curl );
        fwrite ( $fp, $contents );
    }

    curl_close ( $curl );
    fclose ( $fp );
}

echo rand(1, 425).get_remote_file_to_cache();
```

Comment: Any answer to this will work only temporarily, at best. Google actively work to stop this sort of thing, they'll modify the HTML, move things around, obfuscate results & if you make too many requests, ban your IP or stick a captcha up

Comment: This is not for an active project that will query hundreds of times per day, I want to learn from it, its more educational to myself ;)

Comment: OK so the banning/captcha issue won't affect you, but any success in extracting the results will still only be temporary until the format of the results page changes (which could be the next time you load it). You'd need to look through the downloaded HTML file for the bits you want (title & URL) & see if you can write some regexes to extract these. Bear in mind this is google's crown jewels - don't underestimate how much effort they put into ensuring that exactly this sort of thing can't be reliably automated. I wish you good luck :)

Comment: Yep, I totally agree that they would be throwing some sort of ban hammer for people who do this regularly,  but I doubt they will care if I do this a few times a day for two days or so :) ( its not critical either so if it does not work in a day or two, no problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can search trough the HTML using [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/domdocument) and [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

```php
// Temp:
$sPageHTML = '<html><head></head><body><div class="test">Text here</div></body></html>';

$oDomDocument = new DOMDocument ( );
$oDomDocument->loadHTML ( $sPageHTML );

// Now, search the DOM structure for all divs with class "test".
$oXPath = new DOMXPath ( $oDomDocument );
$results = $oXPath->query ( '//div[@class="test"]' );

// Loop through the results.
foreach ( $results as $result )
{
    echo 'Innertext: ' . $result->nodeValue;
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

If you are still searching, you can find an open source php google scraper here:
http://scraping.compunect.com/?scrape-google-search  (scroll to bottom for the code)

You can just copy the DOM parsing routines from it, they work very well.